# Serialize nad Deserialize from this same Class by Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, deserialization

I have problem how to create one class definition to serialize and deserialize object with this same result.

This class definition :

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://hl7.org/fhir")]
    public partial class PatientName
    {

        private PatientNameFamily familyField;

        private PatientNameGiven givenField;

        /// <remarks/>
        public PatientNameFamily family
        {
            get
            {
                return this.familyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.familyField = value;
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        public PatientNameGiven given
        {
            get
            {
                return this.givenField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.givenField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://hl7.org/fhir")]
    public partial class PatientNameFamily
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://hl7.org/fhir")]
    public partial class PatientNameGiven
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

[System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://hl7.org/fhir")]
    public partial class PatientNameFamily
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://hl7.org/fhir")]
    public partial class PatientNameGiven
    {

        private string valueField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
        public string value
        {
            get
            {
                return this.valueField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.valueField = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

serialize correct to XML like below :

```
<name>      
<family value="Senior"/>  
<given value="Sylwester"/>
</name>
```

but when try to deserialize JSON :  `{\"family\": \"Seniorka\",\"given\": [ \"Sylwia\" ]} ]`
I have  exception :

Error converting value "Seniorka" to type 'PlatformaP1ATD.ZM.PatientNameFamily, of course i can change class definition to string and Array of String , but I wan`t to have two class to serialze to xml ande deserialze from JSON.

Any idea how to convert string value to nested type ?

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Name name = new Name() { family = new Family() { value = "Senior" }, given = new Given() { value = "Sylwester" } };

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Name));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, name);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot("name")]
    public class Name
    {
        public Family family { get; set; }
        public Given given { get; set; }
    }
    public class Family
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
    public class Given
    {
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Object to XML look okey , but from  
`String jsonString = "{\"family\": \"Seniorka\",\"given\": [ \"Sylwia\" ]} "; ` this same error

Comment: Look like you just have to remove the square brackets.